# How I can set sql_mode in vitess v6.0.20-20200508

Tags: mysql, vitess

I am using latest vitess v6.0.20-20200508 and MySQL version 5.7. Without updating the MySQL version I want remove "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY" from sql_mode. Can anyone please help me?
I tried with

```
SET global sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,',''));
```

in the vttablet, But it is not updating sql_mode. I want to set it while starting sql server. I have also tried in vttablet-up.sh file by adding the

```
SET global sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,',''));
```

But it is still not updating sql_mode. Please help!

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Setting of global or session variables is not yet supported in vitess. For global, we recommend pre-initializing the database with the necessary settings. This can be done through init_db.sql that vitess uses to initialize the instances it brings up.

Support for setting session variables is what we're working on next. It should be out very soon.

Comment: Is it added now ? @Sugu